# How can I specify in the filter the presence of certain objects?

Tags: django

How can I specify in the filter the presence of certain objects? I have a ManyToManyField called members. I need to create a query where I specify that this object will only have 2 members: user1, user2.
I write `Model.objects.filter(members=[user1,user2])` But django returns me all models that have one of their user1, user2.

Comment: `Model.objects.filter(members__in=[user1,user2]).annotate(nmembers=Count('members')).filter(nmembers=2)`

Comment: Why doesn't this query work for me? Model.objects.filter(members__in=[user]).annotate(nmembers=Count('members')).filter(nmembers=1). It gives out objects with the presence of this user. And for 2 or more, it works correctly.

Comment: sorry, there is still an error, should be: `Model.objects.annotate(nmembers=Count('members', filter=Q(members__in=[user1,user2])), allmem=Count('members')).filter(nmembers=2, allmem=2)`

Comment: Oh cool, it works. Thanks again. Can you please explain how this request works? With Count, Q, F, didn't work yet. So I understand roughly what they are doing, but for example why allmem is needed - no.